# Is there a way to check the php version number just using files on the hard drive?

Tags: php, version, debian

I have a hard drive that used to be in a server, now I'm trying to find out what exact version of php was installed on the server.  I know it was version 4 because the folder it's in is /etc/php4, but I'm wondering if there is a config file, or some file somewhere that would tell me what exact version it is.  I check php.ini and that didn't have it.  The OS was debian.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can find the `php` executable, you can probably extract the version number from within using the `strings` utility on Linux. In my case (Ubuntu Linux), it's in `/usr/bin/php`.

If I then run

```
# strings /usr/bin/php | grep X-Powered-By
```

I get:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.2-1ubuntu4.9
```

If you can't find that string, try this:

```
# strings /usr/bin/php | grep buildd
```

for which I get (lots of examples of the version number there):

```
/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/ext/phar/phar.c
/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/ext/phar/phar_object.c
/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/ext/soap/soap.c
/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/ext/standard/assert.c
/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/main/main.c
/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/main/output.c
/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/Zend/zend_alloc.c
/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/Zend/zend_opcode.c
/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/Zend/zend_alloc_canary.c
/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/Zend/zend_objects_API.c
/build/buildd/php5-5.3.2/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h
```

Telling me that the PHP version is 5.3.2.

Comment: Man, great solution, but I don't seem to have strings command.  i'm using Debian squeeze.  unfortunately not finding much by way of google on how to get strings on debian.  Any ideas, much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't know Debian well, but try `apt-get install strings`.

Comment: Got it.  apt-get install binutils did the trick, then using the strings command worked like a charm.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the news.txt file in the directory should contain the build number. *Or at least mine does...*

```
PHP                                                                        NEWS
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
22 Jul 2010, PHP 5.2.14
```

In-fact, both installs do:

```
PHP                                                                        NEWS
|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||
17 Mar 2011, PHP 5.3.6
```

Comment: Thanks, which directory do you have that in? I'm not finding it, maybe because it's php 4.

Answer (score 0):

Or just run a quick

```
phpinfo();
```

in a sample php file.

Comment: Thanks, apache, and php are not actually running.  I just have the hard drive.  I need to find out the version number, just based on what files/directories are on the disk.